# How do I generate ~50 microamps of DC across dynamic resistance?

Tags: dc, circuit-design, breadboard

How do I generate ~50 microamps of steady direct current across a load (tissue sample) with dynamic resistance that varies between 2kohm and 20kohm with good visibility into circuit operating conditions and safeguards against elevated current and voltage?

Ideally the power source will be an over the counter battery.

*Update: I completely missed the existence of constant current ICs, but see the answers for additional info on monitoring and alternatives.*

Comment: This is way to vague of a "specification" for getting any guidance. For this reason this is likely to get closed.

Comment: You want a 50 micro-amp constant-current supply? Is the required output voltage to achieve this guaranteed to be lower than your battery voltage?

Comment: If your a beginner I suggest you try a http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf understand how it works and then proceed to higher spec solutions

Comment: (1) "*Resistance of the load is dynamic and unknown.*" You have to decide on some limits. (2) "*But at least the voltage needs to be adjustable.*" Again, between what limits? (3) If you just explain the application you'll get better answers.

Comment: I think you need to describe what the overall problem is.

Comment: Constant current source, linear makes some good ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A brief review of the specifications leads to:

- Constant current of 50 µA into 20 kΩ (worst case) gives required voltage \$ V = IR = 50µ \times 20k = 1000 mV = 1 \; V \$. This should be easy to do from a 9 V battery.

> A circuit that can provide ~50 microamps of steady direct current to a 1 square inch electrode applied to heterogeneous tissues with good visibility into circuit operating conditions and safeguards against elevated current.

I think you can satisfy both requirements by using a 50 µA constant current source which is limited to some maximum voltage at the terminals.

- The constant current source may eliminate the need to read the current. Since it is constant we need only read the voltage to calculate the resistance from \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {V}{50µ} \$.
- Since 1 V is adequate to drive the required current an upper limit of 1.2 V seems reasonable to give you some headroom.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fog2P0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Very sketchy outline of required system.*

- I1 is the current source. It needs to have the upper voltage control built in.
- VM1 is shown for reference. The voltage across your tissue sample would appear here.
- A simple micro such as an Arduino or any of the others would provide a simple means of reading, scaling, averaging, etc., the readings and outputting to a display or logger.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider starting with a classic design:  an earthed constant current circuit based on an opamp.  [Here is a site showing the construction of one (with somewhat different specification, but similar design):](http://www.instructables.com/id/Constant-Current-Source-with-Operational-Amplifier/).  These parts are cheap.

Instead of a resistor, adding a zener diode can give better stability with respect to changes in the source voltage, as in the diagram below.  Roughly the current through the load is the breakdown voltage of the zener diode (5v?) divided by the resistance R3.  Being a bit lazy tonight, I just grabbed the default opamp and transistor from circuit lab, so you'd probably want to look around for good ones for this application.  But this should give you a start.  As is, it seemed to give current close to 50 microamp when the load varied from 2k to 20k.

(My ancient Electronic Designer's Handbook used the venerable uA741 as the op amp, but the circuit lab default TL081 also has minimum 7v supply voltage).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f25Bw5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> I completely missed the existence of constant current ICs,

Basicallybtwo ways to do it, assuming a fixed voltage supply.

1. A constant current source. It is essentially a voltage source in serial with a huge resistance. The resistance is much greater than that of the load so the current is determined primarily by the serial resistance. This is an open loop solution.
2. A serial resistor that varies with the load to maintain a constant current. You typically need negative feedback plus a sampling mechanism for this to work.